# traer informacion segun el usuario logueado mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo una base de datos con dos tablas, relacionadas entre si por ID. La **T1** contiene todo el registro de un usuario principal, y la **T2** contiene usuarios alternativos ligados al ID del usuario principal.

Lo que necesito hacer es que cuando un **usuario alternativo** inicie sesión, se cargue la columna `TOKEN` del usuario alternativo en lugar de la columna `TOKEN` del usuario principal, para poder registrar automaticamente el código del usuario que inicio sesión.

Tabla 1 usuario principal

```
id |  usuario  | password | token |
-----------------------------------
1  | Andres    | *****    | e12A1 |
-----------------------------------
2  | Maria     | *****    | HJb71 |
-----------------------------------
```

Tabla 2 usuarios alternativos

```
id |  usuario  | password | token | id_ppl |
--------------------------------------------
1  | Juana     | *****    |       | 1      |
--------------------------------------------
2  | Martin    | *****    |       | 1      |
--------------------------------------------
```

PHP => Aqui necesito reemplazar el token del usuario ppl con el token del usuario alternativo.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT T1.* FROM escolar AS T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN users_extra AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id_ppl");

    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$usuario, $password); 
     $stmt->execute(); 
     $stmt->store_result(); 
     if($stmt->num_rows > 0){ 
     $stmt->bind_result($id, $usuario, $token);
     $stmt->fetch();

    $user = array(
     'id' => $id,
     'usuario' => $usuario,
     'token' => $token
     );
```

Mi intento era hacer algo así:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT T1.* 
(SELECT T1.token FROM escolar AS T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN users_extra AS T2 ON T1.token = T2.token) AS token_alt
FROM escolar AS T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN users_extra AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id_ppl");
```

Pero no supe como seguir, estoy aprendiendo PHP **soy novato**, y pues pensé que quizás al obtener el token alternativo, por medio de un condicional podría reemplazarlo con el principal.

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si lo que quieres es el token alternativo haz la query directamente a la tabla T2. La tabla T1 no la necesitas para nada.

Answer (score 0):

Aclaremos un par de cosas primero;

- Necesitas que cuando un usuario alternativo inicie sesion hacer una peticion a la base de datos y devolver el toke de este no? El token de este usuario alternativo?
- Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior, necesitas algun dato del usuario princiapl? O nada de nada?
- Es posible que te hayas equivocado y lo que necesitas es que cuando el usuario alternativo inicie sesion devolver el token del usuario principal al que este pertenece??

---

Tal como he entendido esta es mi solucion(*Cambiare la respuesta si resulta no serlo*):

 Haz una query simple a la cual le pasas el `id` del usuario que necesites el token, en php quedaria tal que asi:

```
$idUser; // Variable que contiene el id del usuario del cual necesitas le token
$sql = "SELECT token FROM users_extra WHERE id=$idUser";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```